# Block Based DCT on gray images

Tags: image-processing, dct

Can IDCT give negative values after applying it to block based DCT channels?
I divided the gray image in 4*4 blocks and they took the 4*4 DCT of the blocks. Then using those blocks i created DCT channels. Each channel contained the spread of a frequency over the image.

Comment: Please show a **Minimum Complete Verifiable Example**. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: code is not required, the question is about a mathematical property. In fact the question does not belong here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can. The DCT is a sum of cosines, which have zero mean. So you may very well have nonzero pixels with negative weights only.